# Randomly unable to connect to ec2 instance from some networks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

Randomly I am unable to connect to ec2 instance from office network and some others.
When it happens I am unable to ping ec2 instance from this networks, but if I use a VPN it return to work correctly.

It works fine outside the office network and with 4G hotspot.
Looks like something is getting blocked in specific networks.

Security groups seems configured well
[inbound/outbound rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GCaS.png)

Comment: When it happens, have you tried to login via `session manager` and check `ram , cpu etc`? Can it be a coincidence that you are able to login via `VPN` but the issue is not related to network ?

Comment: Yes, but ram, cpu etc have standard consume level, and during it happen i can anyway navigate from other networks correctly. It seems that is not a coincidence because when i turn vpn on I start navigate and stop instantly when i turn it off

Comment: Something with the NACLs?

Comment: This is NACL config, same for outbound https://i.ibb.co/mzyh6Kf/NACL.png

Comment: Do you have `VPC flow logs` enabled? If not, you can enable them for a particular `subnet` or even a `network interface`. You can do it for your `EC2`'s network interface and check if the requests arrive at all. I am thinking the issue is with your internet and not with `Ec2`. Do you have other resources in the same VPC/subnet where you can ping/telnet when this happens again?

Comment: I will enable flow logs. Yes I have other res on same VPC wich I can ping correctly during the problem happens

Comment: I have enabled the flow log and this is the result [link] (https://i.ibb.co/0rBTLDS/Cattur2.png). On 31-01-2022 from 3:14 to 3:20 GMT + 01: 00 approximately the problem occurred on a machine with ip highlighted in blue in the file; on the log everything looks ok

Comment: This is the tracert on machine connected to network with the error (while error occurs) https://i.ibb.co/QmwXQFj/err.png